# JPA issue with H2 in apache-tomee

Tags: h2, openjpa, apache-tomee

I am trying a sample JPA application in apache-tomee-plus-1.6.0.2. The database being used is H2.

When I try to redeploy the webapp there is `Database may be already in use: Locked by another process.` exception in tomee log. Actually I see the lock being held and not released when the webapp is redeployed.

Please find the content of the relevant files.

**context.xml**

```
<Resource
        name="jdbc/ContactsDB"
        auth="Container"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        driverClassName="org.h2.Driver"
        url="jdbc:h2:./repository/deployment/server/webapps/jpa-contacts-database/contacts;"
        username="sa"
        password="sa"
        JtaManaged="true"/>
```

**persistence.xml**

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">
<persistence-unit name="ContactsUnit">
    <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
    <class>org.wso2.appserver.sample.ee.cdi.jpa.jaxws.Contact</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="buildSchema"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"></property>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

**ContactManagerImpl.java**

```
package org.wso2.appserver.sample.ee.cdi.jpa.jaxws;

import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.Stateful;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContextType;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

@Stateful
@Named
public class ContactManagerImpl implements ContactManager {
private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(ContactManagerImpl.class);

@PersistenceContext(name = "ContactsUnit", type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
EntityManager entityManager;

@Override
public String addContact(Contact contact) throws Exception {
    try {
        entityManager.persist(contact);
        return "Contact was saved successfully.";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        return "Error Occurred : " + e.getMessage();
    }
}

@Override
public List<Contact> getContacts() {
    Query query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT Contact contact FROM Contact contact");
    return query.getResultList();
}

}
```

How can I overcome this issue? Am I doing anything wrong in code/configuration here?

Comment: getting error during development or deployment

Comment: when I deploy it the first time it works, but when I try to redeploy, the error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Giving a url outside the webapps directory solved the problem. For example I chose ~/h2webdb/webui